# Sending notification to a specific type of user and save the notification in the database using django channels

Tags: django, database, database-design, django-channels

I want to send notification to a specific group of users. Let's say the specific group is Admin. When an user register on my site after admin approval the user will be activate. For this admin needs to be notified. The main problem was with the database design. I need to save the notification.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    view_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notification_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='notification_sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='notification_receiver')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    redirect_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the model. Here **recipient** will be the admin. Now main problem is there will be more than 1 admin. If i want to save the notification the solution came to in my mind is that to iterate through the **User** model find the admin and send each admin notification which is not a good solutions. Django channels doc shows there is a way to send multiple user using **gruop_send()** yes I can use that but how can I save the notification in the db with multiple recipient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a many-to-many relationship between `Notification` and `User` to associate multiple recipients to a single notification:

```py
class Notification(models.Model):
    view_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notification_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='notification_sender')
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='notification_receivers')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    redirect_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then to access recipients:

```py
notification = Notification.objects.get(id=1)
recipients = notification.recipients.all()
```